# Can you put labels between horizontal bars?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I am plotting a horizontal, stacked bar chart. The labels for my bars are very long. Is there a way I can put them above their corresponding bar? Otherwise, the space on my page is not used well, the plot will be displayed very small. Here is my code and plot:

[image: I'd like to put "Zivildienst" and "Katastrophenschutz" above the bars, not to the left of them.]

**I'd like to put "Zivildienst" and "Katastrophenschutz" above the bars, not to the left of them.**

```
data3 <- data.frame(System=rep(c('Zivildienst', 'Katastrophenschutz'), each=5),
                    Einstellung=rep(c('Sehr unwahrscheinich','Eher unwahrscheinlich','Weiss nicht','Eher wahrscheinlich','Sehr wahrscheinlich'), times=2),
                    Anzahl=c(131, 142, 283, 421, 981, 54, 140, 490, 418, 856))
level_order <- c('Zivildienst', 'Katastrophenschutz') 


# Get the levels for "Einstellung" in the required order
data3$Einstellung = factor(data3$Einstellung, levels = c('Weiss nicht','Sehr unwahrscheinich','Eher unwahrscheinlich','Eher wahrscheinlich','Sehr wahrscheinlich'))
data3 = arrange(data3, System, desc(Einstellung))

# Calculate the percentages
data3 = ddply(data3, .(System), transform, percent = Anzahl/sum(Anzahl) * 100)

# Format the labels and calculate their positions
data3 = ddply(data3, .(System), transform, pos = (cumsum(Anzahl) - 0.5 * Anzahl))
data3$label = paste0(sprintf("%.0f", data3$percent), "%")

cbPalette <- c("#999999", "#2A7AD4", "#5C96D7", "#D3A253", "#D48F1D")

# Plot
ggplot(data3, aes(x = factor(System), y = Anzahl, fill = Einstellung)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = .3) +
  geom_text(aes(y = pos, label = label), size = 4) +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        aspect.ratio = .3) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=cbPalette)+
  coord_flip()+
  ggtitle("Werden Sie sich für die Alternative entscheiden?", subtitle = "2000 Männer befragt") + labs(x = NULL)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using *facet*:

```
#fix the order of factors
data3$System <- factor(data3$System, levels = c("Zivildienst", "Katastrophenschutz"))

#plot with facets
ggplot(data3, aes(x = System, y = Anzahl, fill = Einstellung)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(aes(y = pos, label = label), size = 4) +
  coord_flip() +
  facet_wrap(vars(System), ncol = 1, scales = "free_y") +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0, 0)) +            # make bar "fuller"
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +          # make bar "fuller"
  scale_fill_manual(values = cbPalette) +
  ggtitle("Werden Sie sich für die Alternative entscheiden?", 
          subtitle = "2000 Männer befragt") + 
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        aspect.ratio = .3,
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        strip.background = element_rect(fill = NA),# remove facet strip background
        strip.text = element_text(hjust = 0)       # left align the facet strip text
        )
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You would need to do this by removing the axis text and adding custom labels with `geom_text`

```r
ggplot(data3, aes(x = factor(System), y = Anzahl, fill = Einstellung)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = .3) +
  geom_text(aes(y = pos, label = label), size = 4) +
  geom_text(aes(y = 0, label = System, x = factor(System)), size = 5,
            hjust = 0, nudge_x = 0.3, check_overlap = TRUE) +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        aspect.ratio = .3) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=cbPalette)+
  coord_flip()+
  ggtitle("Werden Sie sich für die Alternative entscheiden?", 
          subtitle = "2000 Männer befragt") + 
  labs(x = NULL) +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank())
```

[image]